# list all services

Tags: upstart, services, init, init.d

There are two ways you could do this `service --status-all`. The other way is to do `initctl list`. I would like to know the difference. some services like mysql do not show up in `initctl list`, and some like 'nova-api' do not show up in `service --status-all`. 
How do I get the complete list in one go.

Comment: see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/422178/146791).

Comment: thanks. but my quest is still incomplete. the answer says services managed by upstart appear with ? in `service --status-all` but they don't. I've checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read "service --status-all" results](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407075/how-to-read-service-status-all-results)

Comment: @Fabby You have given me the same like from first comment again.

Comment: `service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apparmor
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ ? ]  binfmt-support` is what I get... What is your output for the first 6 lines???

Comment: Alright I'll edit my post with more information on what I am looking for.

Comment: Adding more information. I am working on openstack and I can see that none of my openstack services(nova-api, nova-compute, neutron-server etc) show up in service --status-all. not even with a '?'. They all show up in initctl list. I want to know why this is happenning. My intentions are only to understand the system better, because I am planning on writing an upstart service myself and want to do it the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use too:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service
```

or

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

or

```
service --status-all
```

Maybe this link can help you : [service vs. initctl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/353382/service-vs-initctl)